# FormType array (JSON) to mulitple inputs

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

Within my entity, I have a JSON type, which is just a coordinate `x:y`.

In my form, I would like to display this field as two TextType, one for `x`, another for `y`.

Any idea on how I should proceed to achieve this?

Comment: Did you consider to use data transformers https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/data_transformers.html?

Comment: I don't understand why somebody would down vote a question that just makes sense. Down voting is a feature that is killing stackoverflow. Everything I post is down voted too. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: another possibility is to have the 2 
TextType x and y fields as non mapped ('mapped' => false) and concatenate them before persisting the entity.

Comment: yeah, I thought about the two TextType @KarimMtl though it's just extra work somehow. But works that way

Comment: Great I am glad you have at least something working. Hopefully somebody will suggest a solution that works better for you. Don't get discouraged by the -1. It is unfortunate that for some people it is more meaningful to down vote others questions than providing solutions.

Comment: Just did un upvote to provide some balance :-)